# Evitar mais de um cadastro no banco de dados

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou tento problemas, pois estou fazendo um sistema de comunidade onde o usuário se registra e compartilha histórias.

Mais quando fui testar cliquei em registrar 2 vezes e 2 vezes ele foi para o banco de dados mesmo com um função verificando.

```
MYSQL:
CAMPO    |  TIPO
ID       |  INT (AutoIncrement)
USERNAME |  VARCHAR(12)
PASSWORD |  VARCHAR(12)
EMAIL    |  TEXT
```

Quando se registra ele executa o seguinte código:

```php
<?php
    include ('mysql_connector.php');

    $username = "";
    $email = "";
    $password = "";

    if(!empty($_POST)){

        if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password']) ){

            $msg = "";

            try{

                $username = $_POST['username'];
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $password = $_POST['password'];

                if(!exite_ja_registrado()){
                    $cmd = "INSERT INTO `users`(`id`, `username`, `email`,`password`) VALUES(NULL, '$username', '$email', '$password')";
                    $result = mysql_query($cmd);
                    if(!$result){
                        echo $error = mysql_error($result);
                        echo "<script>alert('$error');</alert>";
                    }

                    else{
                        echo "<script>alert('Usuario registrado! Faça login agora!');</script>";
                    }
                }

                else if (exite_ja_registrado()){
                    echo "<script>alert('Já exite um usuário registrado com os mesmo dados! Faça login...');</alert>";
                }
            }

            catch (Exception $e){
                echo "<script>alert('Usuario, Email e Senha ja registrados!')</script>";
            }
        }
    }


?>
<html>
<body>
<?php include('google-analytics.php'); ?>
<center>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" placeHolder="Email" name="email" /><br>
    <input type="text" placeHolder="usuário" name="username" /><br>
    <input type="password" placeHolder="Senha" name="password" /><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Registrar" />
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Mas mesmo depois de pressionar inúmeras vezes ele coloca os dados novamente no mysql.

Faça o teste => http://brasilr2.net76.net/analytics/register.php

```
function exite_ja_registrado(){
            $cmd = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email`='$email' AND `password`='$password' AND `username`='$username'";
            $result = mysql_query($cmd);
            if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1){ return true; }
            else { return false; }
        }
```

> Refiz o código inteiro e agora ele não adiciona mais de um valor, mas também não avisa ao usuário que já tem os dados cadastrados:

```php
<?php
    include ('mysql_connector.php');

    $username = "";
    $email = "";
    $password = "";

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" && !empty($_POST)){

        if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password']) ){

            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            $existe = ExistUser($username, $email);

            if(!$existe){
                $cmd = "INSERT INTO `users`(`id`, `username`, `email`,`password`) VALUES(NULL, '$username', '$email', '$password')";
                $result = mysql_query($cmd);
                if(!$result){
                    echo "<script>alert('Já exite um usuário registrado com os mesmo dados! Faça login...');</alert>";
                }

                else{
                    echo "<script>alert('Usuario registrado! Faça login agora!');</script>";
                }
            }

            else{
                echo "<script>alert('Já exite um usuário registrado com os mesmo dados! Faça login...');</script>";
            }
        }
    }

    function ExistUser($u, $e){

        $cmd = "SELECT * FROM `users` (`email`, `username`) WHERE `username`='$u' AND `email`='$e'";
        $result = mysql_query($cmd);
        $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

        if(1 == $rows){
            return true;
        }

        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Registre-se para continuar...</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php include('google-analytics.php'); ?>
<center>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" placeHolder="Email" name="email" /><br>
    <input type="text" placeHolder="usuário" name="username" /><br>
    <input type="password" placeHolder="Senha" name="password" /><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Registrar" />
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

E agora da esse erro:

> Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a1478344/public_html/analytics/register.php on line 40

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui solucionar da seguinte maneira:

Executando a query no banco de dados para ver se o usuario e email já existem! se sim retorna true.
se não retorna false.

```php
function ExisteUsuario($u, $e){

        $cmd = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$u' AND `email`='$e'";
        $result = mysql_query($cmd);
        $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

        if(1 == $rows){
            return true;
        }

        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

E na consulta do registro coloca-se o seguinte:

utiliza $existe = ExisteUsuario(nome de usuario, email);
se for false ele executa uma query adicionando o usuário ao DB.
se for true ele alerta dizendo que não existe.

```php
$existe = ExisteUsuario($username, $email);

            if(!$existe){
                $cmd = "INSERT INTO `users`(`id`, `username`, `email`,`password`) VALUES(NULL, '$username', '$email', '$password')";
                $result = mysql_query($cmd);
                if(!$result){
                    echo "<script>alert('Já exite um usuário registrado com os mesmo dados! Faça login...');</script>";
                }

                else{
                    echo "<script>alert('Usuario registrado! Faça login agora!');</script>";
                }
            }

            else if($existe){
                echo "<script>alert('Já exite um usuário registrado com os mesmo dados! Faça login...');</script>";
            }
```

Comment: Vejo que conseguiu. Aquele erro que você mostrou, provavelmente a query estava retornando false, e a função não consegue contar linhas de um "false".

Comment: sim, e também foi erro da tag html, eu coloquei `</alert>` não `</script>` depois que eu vi isso!

Comment: @DiegoFelipe meio que estou fazendo um website para um clan de games, e o pessoal pediu. por isso eu me preocupei com a query selecionar tanto o email, tanto o username.

Comment: Certo. Depois marque sua resposta como aceita, creio que só vá liberar em 24hrs, mas é util caso alguem tenha o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 1):

Se o código da sua função exite_ja_registrado() está em outro arquivo, você precisa fazer um include dele no register.php da mesma forma que você fez com o mysql-connector.php

Para ocultar o botão você pode fazer uma chamada no jquery pra ocultar o botão

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>    
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $('#id_do_form').submit(function() {
   $('#img_carregando').show(); // mostra div com imagem CARREGANDO
   $('#botao_gravar').hide(); // oculta botao GRAVAR
   return true; 
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Não é a questão de desabilitar o botão! e sim que quando clica no botão 2 vezes pra enviar ele envia 2 mesmos resultados, só mudando a ID

Comment: sugiro que você cooloque os campos username e email como unique no banco de dados assim o próprio banco vai rejeitar gravações desses dois campos iguais